# Win 7 Taskbar Icons all change to display yellow folders

Tags: taskbar

The Icons all changed to yellow folder icons, not sure what caused this.
Any clues would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Tough to say *why*, but to fix it, I'd start by rebuilding the icon cache, as described in [this article](http://www.winvistaclub.com/t71.html):

1. Open Windows Explorer, and configure your Folder Options > Views to show Hidden / System Files
2. Go to `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Loca`l folder
3. Delete the hidden `IconCache.db` file
4. Reboot